# how to use JointJS with Angular4?

Tags: angular, jointjs

It does not work out of the box (it crashes on an error "b.call is not a function").

In the official [tutorials](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/tutorials/requirejs.html) they say

> we have to trick Backbone to use Lodash instead of Underscore (this
>   is because JointJS requires Lodash, not just Underscore)

this is confusing and seems a bit like hacking. The biggest problem here though is that I have no idea how to do that in Angular4 (which internally uses webpack).

Comment: Well I'm not an expert in package management, but I think that the packages handle their own dependencies, that's why you get a npm_modules folder that is huge. So I'd say you don't have to handle the versions, the packages will do it themselves. What is your issue exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You no need to edit webpack.config. When you install jointjs from npm, also with jointjs are install dependencies of this library, and these dependencies use separately from Angular 4 dependence.
So you just need to import jointjs in your component or where you want to use joint.

```
import * as joint from '../../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js';
```

Also make sure that you set allowJs parameter to true in your tsconfig file:

```
"allowJs": true
```

It will allow import js files to your angular component. That's all that you need.